# How to add footer in latex without the page number

Tags: latex

I have a 2 tex file which I am converting to pdf and then merging the 2 pdf.
My problem is I want to define footer for each pdf without the page numbers.

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{text}
```

but it gives me the page number.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{text}    
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following at the beginning of the document:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Update: @laspal, not sure why it's not working for you.  Here's a basic test I just tried with long table.  The directive above suppressed page numbering while leaving the footers intact on both pages.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\rfoot{footer text}

some text

\begin{longtable}{rr}
\hline
& X  \\ 
\hline
1 &   1 \\ 
2 &   2 \\ 
3 &   3 \\ 

% SNIP: generated lines to span two pages

73 &  73 \\ 
74 &  74 \\ 
75 &  75 \\ 
\hline

\end{longtable}

some more text on second page

\end{document}
```

Comment: But the problem is I am using longtable so my footer comes only one the first page. Basically my tables is in two pages. 
Help??